# Indexing using pg_trgm module not working while using more than one OR operator in the where condition inside the query in postgresql 9.4

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

Indexing using pg_trgm module not working for me while using more than one `OR` operator in the `where` condition. Query is given below.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
SELECT * 
FROM registration 
where 
    data->>'firstName' LIKE '%lali%' OR  
    data->>'spouseName' LIKE '%lali%' OR  
    data->>'vhnName' LIKE '%lali%' OR 
    data ->> 'subCentreName' LIKE '%lali%'
```

When I run the above I get sequence scan but I expect index scan to happen.

I am using JsonB.

I tried out both gist and gin indexing for all the columns mentioned in the `where` clause in above query but indexing didn't work for both.

How to do indexing for the case if we use multiple `OR` operators inside `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

A pattern starting with `%` is worthless in a index search since it can start with anything.

Comment: I could find that index scan is working for the query- explain select * from registration where data ->> 'firstName' LIKE 'lal%' OR data ->> 'spouseName' LIKE '%lali%' . But when I add one more OR condition inside the where clause- explain select * from registration where data ->> 'firstName' LIKE 'lal%' OR data ->> 'spouseName' LIKE '%lali%' OR data ->> 'subCentreName' LIKE '%lali%'  , index scan is not working and sequential scan is happening instead. I am a bit confused about this behaviour.